How can I convert two object with ora2pg in one command?
I am working on a migration project from Oracle to Postgres. The goal is to convert objects with ora2pg.
It works when I use a command for each object, in this example a package named source_package:
ora2pg -p -t PACKAGE -n namespace -a source_package \
       -u password -w password -o target_packge.pg.sql \
       -l log_file11.log -c ora2pg.conf --no_header -P 0 -J 0

but when I use a command to convert two objects in a single command it does not work. The following command converts all the types and packages in the database in question:
ora2pg -p -t TYPE,PACKAGE -n namespace -a "type,source_package" \
       -u password -w password -o test2object.pg.sql \
       -l log_file11.log -c ora2pg.conf --no_header -P 0 -J 0

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?
